# mysql add foreign key constraint error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables which I'd like to connect with foreign key constraint

For some reason, when I try to do it, it fails and and says: `#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint`

Here is my first table:

```
CREATE TABLE `zmaneyhayom` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `zman_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `tempHour` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `tempHourType` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `tempHourNum` double NOT NULL,
 `tempMinutes` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `tempMinutesType` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `tempMinutesNum` double NOT NULL,
 `regularMinutes` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `regularMinutesNum` double NOT NULL,
 `equivalentMinutes` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `equivalentMinutesNum` double NOT NULL,
 `degreesBelowHorizon` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `degreesBelowHorizonNum` double NOT NULL,
 `beforeAfter` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
 `riseSet` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `zman_id_2` (`zman_id`),
 KEY `zman_id` (`zman_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And this table holds ID and name, which eventually the ID in this table is the name for the previous table (zman_id column):

```
CREATE TABLE `zmaneyhayomlabels` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

This is the code I'm attempting in order to create the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE  `zmaneyhayom` ADD FOREIGN KEY (  `zman_id` ) REFERENCES  `luah_v2`.`zmaneyhayomlabels` (

`id`
) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
```

I have no idea why it's failing :/

What I want is that whenever I go on phpmyadmin and go to the first table, instead of typing some id in `zman_id` I will have a select box which I can select a name (which is stored in the second table) but the value it will store will be the ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they are not same type  id is INT and zman_id is varchar.

you can change this

```
 `zman_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
```

to

```
 `zman_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Thanks it did work. How can I do that whenever I create a new record on `zmaneyhayom` when I'm required to pick a `zman_id`, I can pick a value from `zmaneyhayomlabels` instead of typing a value?

Comment: didnt understand what you mean, but glad you get it working now :).

Comment: I will try to explain my self. `zmaneyhayom` has a column named `zman_id`. `zmaneyhayomlabels` has a column named `id`, when I use phpmyadmin in order to add records to `zmaneyhayom` I need to choose `zman_id`. Now, instead of typing 4,5,10 etc.. I will have a select box which I can choose value from. The value is coming from the table `zmaneyhayomlabels` and related by ID, so if I have a record in `zmaneyhayomlabels` which is: 1-test, in the select box I will be able to select `test` and when I add the record, it will save the `zman_id` value as 1(not the label name, but the id)